# Is it possible to make 64bit debian package depend on a 32bit deb package

Tags: ubuntu, debian, deb

We build our package for both 32 bit and 64 bit, but one dependency debian package (from a 3rd party, only has 32 bit version, it doesn't require other dependency). I just wonder if it is possible to make the 64bit deb package dependent on a 32bit deb package? Or is there other ways to work around? 
    Thanks!

LJ

Comment: What specifically in the package will you depend on?  Executables?   Libraries?  Docs?  Header files?  Images?

Comment: it is a driver for hasp key.

Comment: OK so it's software of some kind for a security key.  Is it an executable, a library, or a proper kernel driver you have to install using `sudo`?

Comment: I think they are executables, I check the debian package and check the property of the file, it says executable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very very broad. Anyway I suggest you have a look at `wine` [package](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/wine) which depends either on `wine64` or `wine32`.

---

Of course, you need to setup your amd64 box to be multiarch capable, as indicated [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I will check it!

Comment: it is solved by adding Multi-Arch: foreign, and dep*.deb: i386 to the dependency list. Thanks.